# Passing signature public key along with the signature

Tags: encryption, signature

Can anybody explain me a sense of passing a public key along with signature which is practiced in SAML 2.0? As I know signature is needed to make sure the message was not intercepted by someone, so I need to make sure the public key I'm validating the signature with is pertained to the sender, which in case of in SAML 2.0 I can get with metadata beforehand. However if I take a public key from the message in run-time, how can I know it is not intercepted and other interceptor's public key is included?

Answer (score 0):

You not only want to validate that the public key matches the signature, you also want to validate that the public key itself is valid. This is generally done through a certificate chain, where each certificate in the chain is basically a signed public key. You need to ensure that each certificate is valid (has not expired, has not been revoked) and that you trust the signers of each certificate. Be careful who you trust and pay attention to revocation.

Comment: Ok, I see your point, but my concern is it may take fair amount of time to validate that public key is valid, it is http request to external resource to check it up, right? Performance would suffer if I make it for every incoming SAML 2.0 assertion